# Restart remote supervisor

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, server, ssh

I have number of web servers say **ServerA** and **ServerB** running **supervisor**. I want the supervisor to be restarted from a remote machine say **ServerRemote**.

I tried to run the below from **ServerRemote**

```
sudo systemctl -H user_in_serverA@ServerA restart supervisor
```

I got the following error

```
Permission denied (publickey).
Could not watch jobs: Connection reset by peer
```

Note that I have **ssh** working fine. The keys are in place.

Comment: So, as user `root` you can `ssh user_in_serverA@ServerA` without a password? And `user_in_serverA` can locally restart the service without giving a password?

Comment: Yes. `user_in_serverA` can ssh and he is in `sudoer` in `ServerA`. `sudo systemctl restart supervisor` works for the user.

Comment: But you are executing `sudo systemctl...` which calls `systemctl` as user `root`. So user `root` has to be able to ssh passwordless with `ssh  user_in_serverA@ServerA`

Comment: Yes you are right. But how do I do that in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. All I want is to remotely start, stop or restart services.